# Why is DDPG not learning and it does not converge?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorflow, python, convergence, ddpg

I have used a different setting, but DDPG is not learning and it does not converge. I have used these codes [1](https://github.com/liampetti/DDPG/blob/master/ddpg.py),[2](https://github.com/maxmax1992/DDPG-MADDPG/blob/b8bc4c75dc5ba765c91f82b351b32b28a0211f3d/DDPG_agent.py), and [3](https://github.com/agakshat/tensorflow-ddpg) and I used different optimizers, activation functions, and learning rate but there is no improvement.

```
    parser.add_argument('--actor-lr', help='actor network learning rate', default=0.001)
    parser.add_argument('--critic-lr', help='critic network learning rate', default=0.0001)
    parser.add_argument('--gamma', help='discount factor for critic updates', default=0.95)

    parser.add_argument('--tau', help='soft target update parameter', default=0.001)
    parser.add_argument('--buffer-size', help='max size of the replay buffer', default=int(1e5))
    parser.add_argument('--minibatch-size', help='size of minibatch for minibatch-SGD', default=64)

    # run parameters
    # parser.add_argument('--env', help='choose the gym env- tested on {Pendulum-v0}', default='MountainCarContinuous-v0')
    parser.add_argument('--random-seed', help='random seed for repeatability', default=1234)
    parser.add_argument('--max-episodes', help='max num of episodes to do while training', default=200)
    parser.add_argument('--max-episode-len', help='max length of 1 episode', default=100)
```

[image]

I have trained in the same environment with A2C and it converged.

[image]

Which parameters should I change to make the DDPG converge? Can anyone help me with this?